# Electron: grant access to sudo or keychain without prompt password every time

Tags: node.js, macos, electron

I'm building an app with electron where I need access to the current wifi password (keychain). but every time the app prompts the password dialog to get access to the keychain. Is there a way to grant the access only once?

Comment: Could you not cache the wifi password in your electron app after you first request it?

Comment: @Arcath I need to get the password for any wifi I'm connected to. so every time I connect to the wifi (could be different network) I wanna be able to the password.

Comment: So each time its getting the wifi password for a different network?

Comment: yes, every time I connect to a different network. or even the same one (in case the password was changed the app needs to know the new one)

Comment: looks like you can give apps access to the keychain http://www.tomsguide.com/faq/id-2327887/apps-access-keychain.html

Comment: I saw that page before. that's per entity. Means for each wifi I need to do the same steps.